# GAE-endpont-libs Appengine's jackson library clashes with Android jackson library

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have Eclipse project with Android and GAE.
I use Generate Cloud endpoint library option in Eclipse to generate the endpoints lib. This creates endpoint-libs folder in the android project.
But it creates Jackson-core-2.1.3 jar and properties file in the /lib sub folder in the each of the endpoints-lib subfolders. However I want Jackson-core-2.3.3 (for some locations stuff I do) which I have in the android project/lib folder. Now when I run my android project I get the following error:
Multiple dex files define Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/Base64Variant

This happens because of 2 versions of Jackson-core. Anyone faced this issue before? I have appengine-java-sdk-1.917. I also use Objectify.
Any ideas how I can make appengine use jackson 2.3.3 version?

Comment: Have you added another library projects into your android project?

Comment: Yes - in my android project, I have a lib folder which has jars like Jackson-core-2.3.3, http-core-4.4, gcm.jar, gson-2.1,http-mime-4.3, etc. I need those for the functionality of my android project to work.